# deploy jboss sar at jboss as 7 error

Tags: jboss, sar

Hello i try to deploy jboss sar file on jboss as. My problem is he can recognize end jboss-sar.

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>        
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

With this deploy plugin i get this error

```
[INFO] Could not execute goal deploy on dts.jboss-sar. Reason: D:\Workspace Liferay\DTS_TRUNK\code\dts\dts-sar\target\dts.jboss-sar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

And Question is how can i tell him to looking dts.sar not dts.jboss-sar couse this file dts.sar is there but he ca't see it.

Okey i found somewhere solution and change plugin on

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
                 <configuration>
                    <filename>dts.sar</filename>
                <artifactTypeMappings>
                <artifactTypeMapping type="jboss-sar" mapping="sar"/>
                </artifactTypeMappings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>

                    </execution>
                </executions>   
            </plugin>
```

Now it's look like it was working but have other issue :

```
16:50:14,298 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."dts.sar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."dts.sar".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "dts.sar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_15]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to parse service xml ["/D:/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/jboss-7.0.2/bin/content/dts.sar/META-INF/jboss-service.xml"]
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:94)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
Message: Unexpected element 'server'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:98) [staxmapper-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:59) [staxmapper-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:87)
    ... 6 more

16:50:14,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (pool-1-thread-3) Deployment of "dts.sar" was rolled back with failure message {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"dts.sar\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"dts.sar\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"dts.sar\""}}
16:50:14,304 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Stopped deployment dts.sar in 3ms
```

I have similar issue when i try to deploy other war file and i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

it was easy just remove Mbean from jboss-service.xml