# maven-javadoc-plugin and failsafe-maven-plugin missing when build JBoss Seam examples

Tags: maven, jboss, seam

I'm trying to build JBoss Seam examples using Maven 3.0.4 but I'm getting missing plugin errors:

```
juliano.schroeder remoting-helloworld $ mvn jboss-as:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:jar:2.8 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:jar:2.8
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:failsafe-maven-plugin:jar:2.9 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:failsafe-maven-plugin:2.9: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:failsafe-maven-plugin:2.9 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:failsafe-maven-plugin:jar:2.9
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (21 KB at 29.4 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (11 KB at 15.0 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (1005 B at 0.7 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (1002 B at 0.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.343s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 26 09:58:26 BRT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jboss-as' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/juliano.schroeder/.m2/repository), jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Anyone knows why that happens or what can be done to fix it? Thanks.

EDIT:

settings.xml - https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0kQ0iZ9xNVNR3ZVRW1ldzZielE

pom.xml - https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0kQ0iZ9xNVNakhSVEd3djBiUmM

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml and settings.xml please ?

Comment: It is not letting me post the files in code formatting.

Comment: Don't care about it. Il will do it for you if don't manage. Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: Posted it on google docs, can you download them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per doc says, you should declare a plugin section in build one, in your pom.xml if you want to use it as a command :

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>7.2</version> <!-- or whatever you want -->
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>7.2</version> <!-- or whatever you want -->
        </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The "old" maven-jboss-plugin don't need it because its group is org.codehaus.mojo. But jboss-as one depends on org.jboss.as.plugins.

***EDIT 1 *** :

You may find some examples here : [deploy jboss sar at jboss as 7 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614167/deploy-jboss-sar-at-jboss-as-7-error)

You may ommit this plugin if you configure it into settings.xml : http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Groups

***EDIT 2 *** :

You may also add the good pluginRepository

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Thnanks! It worked. Where can i see that jboss-as plugin depends on org.jboss.as.plugins?

Comment: Glad to help you :). You can find it here : http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html ... but I just googled maven+jboss-as+plugin : http://www.google.fr/search?q=maven+jboss-as+plugin