# Maven jboss plugin error: "no plugin found for prefix jboss-as"

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I get the following error when trying to run the jboss-as:deploy goal.

> No plugin found for prefix 'jboss-as' in the current project and in
>   the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
>   available from the repositories [local (/home/user/.m2/repository),
>   central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

I tried out everything written here [maven-javadoc-plugin and failsafe-maven-plugin missing when build JBoss Seam examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602520/maven-javadoc-plugin-and-failsafe-maven-plugin-missing-when-build-jboss-seam-exa), but no luck. I need to make this plug-in work without having to add anything in the maven settings file (only in pom).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your build section has something like this in it:

```
<build>
...
    <plugins>
    ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <jbossHome>/usr/jboss-4.2.3.GA</jbossHome>
                <serverName>all</serverName>
                <fileName>target/my-project.war</fileName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you should be using **`jboss:deploy`** instead of `jboss-as:deploy`. But if its like:

```
<build>
...
    <plugins>
    ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.Final</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you should be using **`jboss-as:deploy`** instead of `jboss:deploy`.

Both worked for me with a fresh install of maven 3.0.4 with a bare pom.

Comment: Which directory does the deployed package (.ear or .war) get deployed into?  Is it the standalone/deployments folder in jboss 7.1 by default?  How does jboss-maven-plugin know where your jboss 7.1 's standalone/deployment folder is located?

Comment: By Default it does Standalone. You can configure it by reading here: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html

Comment: So i know this is an old question, but i just started having this issue. My pom has the 2nd example and still doesn't like the jboss-as.

Also there are several other people on the same code with the same pom and it works fine for them

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Welsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12879167/1317678) is right.

The first one is located [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/) and the second one [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/).

So, pay attention if you need to use the "jboss-as" goal specifier or the "jboss" goal specifier.